# Must read articles on Java Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading this article on Java Threads: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/memory.doc.html, which I think is must read for any Java developer. What are the other must read articles about Java Threads or threads in general?

Comment: Read the [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601) book. That's pretty good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java 5 Concurrency book recommendations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237980/java-5-concurrency-book-recommendations)

Comment: Wouldn't [The Java Language Specification, Third Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) be better?

Comment: I would suggest to have a look of [when to use what and how](http://article-stack.com/education/java-multithreading-when-to-use-what-why-and-how.amty)

Answer (score 3):

I found the book [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) a good resource. It teaches you everything you need to know about threads and concurrency in Java. I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

http://linux.die.net/man/7/pthreads + **do implement something**

Answer (score 0):

You may find article [Java Thread Gate Pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2009/jw-03-java-concurrency-with-thread-gates.html) useful.

Answer (score 0):

For Java Threading,

- [`Java Concurreny in Practice.`](http://jcip.net/)
- Taming Java Threads

Answer (score 0):

I find articles in IBM developer works very well written. Try search 'thread' in that site:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/java/libraryview.jsp?sort_by=&show_abstract=true&show_all=&search_flag=&contentarea_by=Java+technology&search_by=thread&topic_by=-1&industry_by=-1&type_by=All+Types&ibm-search=Search